# in such a way as to make me fall

Tags: clauses

a. Tom pushed me such that I would fall, but I managed not to.

b. Tom pushed me in such a way that I would fall, but I managed not to.

c. Tom pushed me so that I would fall, but I managed not to.

d. Tom so pushed me that I would fall, but I managed not to.

Which of the above is correct if the intended meaning is

Tom deliberately pushed me in such a way as to make me fall.

Comment: Without the second part 2 and 3 look ok to me. 4 is very formal. I'm not certain about 1 but would never use it. However I think the second part contradicts the first.

Comment: 'So as to make me fall', or 'in an attempt to make me fall'. None of your versions sounds quite right.

Comment: I would simply say "Tom pushed me to make me fall" or "Tom pushed me to try and make me fall" if in normal conversation. People will pick at your grammar if you write "try and X" though — context of where you're using this would probably help give the most natural sentence

Answer (score 1):

I think (a), (b), and (c) are all correct. Of the three, (c) is preferable.

Another option is:

> Tom pushed me to make me fall....

But I think your wording (a, b, c) emphasizes the malice of Tom's behavior. The emphasis is that Tom could have pushed you differently, so that you wouldn't fall. But, instead, he deliberately pushed you so that you would fall.